# insert self mapping entity as a forgien key in hibernate

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, insert, mapping, self-join

Hi I am new to hibernate.

i have a scenario like there are regular services and bundle services(combination of regular services)

i created tables like

```
CREATE TABLE `dealer_service` (
`id_service` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`service_name` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT ,
`short_desc` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT ,
`full_desc` VARCHAR(500) NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT ,
`cost` FLOAT NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT,
`currency` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT ,
`tax` FLOAT NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT ,
`discounts` FLOAT NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT ,

PRIMARY KEY (`id_service`),
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

mapping between regular service and bundle service

```
CREATE TABLE `service_to_services` (
`service_id_main` INT(11) NOT NULL,
`service_id_sub` INT(11) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`service_id_main`, `service_id_sub`)
 )
 COMMENT='maping table between service to service if service is bundle'
  COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
 ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

hibernate class is

import static javax.persistence.GenerationType.IDENTITY;

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "dealer_service")
public class DealerService implements java.io.Serializable {

private Integer                 idService;
private String                  serviceName;
private String                  shortDesc;
private String                  fullDesc;
private String                  offeredBy;
private String                  terms;
private String                  discriminator;
.
    .
    .

private Set<DealerService>      subServices;
```

//setters and getters

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST,
        CascadeType.ALL }, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable( name = "service_to_services",
            joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "service_id_main") },
            inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "service_id_sub") })
public Set<DealerService> getSubServices() {
    return subServices;
}

public void setSubServices(Set<DealerService> subServices) {
    this.subServices = subServices;
}
```

}

now the problem is i have to a one more table called service incident 
the the pojo class is like this ..

```
@Entity
@Table(na me = "service_incident")
public class ServiceIncident implements java.io.Serializable {


private Set<DealerService>selectedServices=  new HashSet<DealerService>(0);


 @ManyToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.ALL }, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable( name = "work_list",
            joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "service_incident_id") },
            inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "dealer_service_id") })
public Set<DealerService> getSelectedServices() {
    return selectedServices;
}

public void setSelectedServices(Set<DealerService> selectedServices) {
    this.selectedServices = selectedServices;
}                                       0);
}
```

while trying to insert selected services in service incident it is through an exception
like

```
 org.springframework.dao.DuplicateKeyException: a different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session: [cc.carcloud.domain.DealerService#2]; nested exception is org.hibernate.NonUniqueObjectException: a different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session: [cc.carcloud.domain.DealerService#2]
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SessionFactoryUtils.convertHibernateAccessException(SessionFactoryUtils.java:662)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateAccessor.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateAccessor.java:412)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.doExecute(HibernateTemplate.java:411)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.executeWithNativeSession(HibernateTemplate.java:374)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.save(HibernateTemplate.java:683)
at cc.carcloud.dao.GenericDaoImpl.save(GenericDaoImpl.java:46)
at cc.carcloud.serviceimpl.ServiceIncidentServiceImpl.add(ServiceIncidentServiceImpl.java:47)
at cc.carcloud.wscontroller.ServiceIncidentWSController.addServiceIncident(ServiceIncidentWSController.java:92)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:213)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:126)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:96)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:617)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:578)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:923)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:789)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:322)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:116)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.DigestAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(DigestAuthenticationFilter.java:209)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:184)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:155)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:602)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.hibernate.NonUniqueObjectException: a different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session: [cc.carcloud.domain.DealerService#2]
at org.hibernate.engine.StatefulPersistenceContext.checkUniqueness(StatefulPersistenceContext.java:590)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.performUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:284)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsDetached(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:223)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:89)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:70)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.fireSaveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:507)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.saveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:499)
at org.hibernate.engine.CascadingAction$5.cascade(CascadingAction.java:218)
at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeToOne(Cascade.java:268)
at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:216)
at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:169)
at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeCollectionElements(Cascade.java:296)
at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeCollection(Cascade.java:242)
at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:219)
at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:169)
at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:130)
at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.cascadeAfterSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:456)
at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:334)
at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:181)
at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:107)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:187)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:33)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:172)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:27)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:70)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.fireSave(SessionImpl.java:535)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:523)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:519)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate$12.doInHibernate(HibernateTemplate.java:686)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate$12.doInHibernate(HibernateTemplate.java:1)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.doExecute(HibernateTemplate.java:406)
... 53 more
```

can any one please help where i am wrong ..

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message exception says what the problem is. You're trying to call `save()`, and thus attach to the session, a detached object. But the session already contains an attached object with the same ID.

It can happen in a situation like the following:

```
DealerService detachedDealerService = new DealerService();
detachedDealerService.setId(2);

DealerService attachedDealerService = session.get(DealerService.class, 2);
session.save(detachedDealerService);
// exception: the dealer service with ID 2 is already in the session
```

Note that, if your IDs are generated automatically, calling `save()` on an object which already has an ID is an error in itself. `save()` is used to create a new persistent object.